# download video file(in MB size) from server using ASIHTTPRequest library

Tags: iphone, download, asihttprequest

In my app, i want to download video files from server and store that file in IPhone document directory.

For downloading i am using ASIHTTPRequest library and i have downloaded the video(in KB size) and stored into Document directory.

but, when i downloading the video(in MB size) means, the request takes more time for that video downloading and there is no result( I have been waiting above 15 mins but there is no download).

I have tried the below code in my app and this is single download from the server.

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.aghaven.com/Downloads/video/Movie.m4v"];

//NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/movie.mov", documentsDirectory];

     ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSString* file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movie.m4v"];

   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
   [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
   [request setDownloadDestinationPath:file];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

 {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                 message:@"Success!!!" 
                                delegate:self 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
 }
```

this file(Movie.m4v) having 2.2 MB size and when i downloading this video from server means, there is no video downloaded.

Kindly suggest me how to download video files (in MB size) from server using ASIHTTPRequest?.

I am using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 sdk.

If any sample code means its very helpful to me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: try using progress var to check when it stops downloading. and just for test purpose comment out set timeout and try again. plus try downloading Image which is more than 2 MB...

Comment: Just a note, ASI is no longer being maintained. You should try to use AFNetworking instead.

Comment: Many Thanks  dontCheckMyBlog, Jacob Relkin..I will look into yours suggestions..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad 

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.aghaven.com/Downloads/video/Movie.m4v"];

     ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/pk/Desktop/my_file.m4v"];
     [request setDelegate:self];
     [request startAsynchronous];

}

 -(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

{

    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                 message:@"Success!!!" 
                                delegate:self 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];

}

 -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    NSLog(@"%@",request.error);

}
```

you will see the file is on desktop.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Hardik Shah!!.. I will check your code and The video file(Movie.m4v) having 2mb size and Is there possible to download that and store it in IPhone document directory?..I want to store video file in IPhone device once it downloaded..Expecting ur answer...

Comment: yes of course, for that you have to just the downloaddestinationpath point to NSDocumentDirectionary. there are so many codes available to save file in document directory.